# Gibbon Gem Mailchimp Form Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailchimp, gibbon

I'm not sure why, but emails aren't being passed through to my Mailchimp list. Clicking the submit button doesn't do anything. Any thoughts?

Gemfile:

```
gem 'gibbon', '~> 1.0.0'
```

index.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag('/welcome/subscribe', method: "post", id: "subscribe", remote: "true") do -%>
   <%= email_field(:email, :address, {id: "email", placeholder: "email address", :class=>"email form-control"}) %>
   <%= submit_tag("Sign me up!", :class=>"btn btn-palette") %>
<% end %>
```

models/welcome.rb:

```
def subscribe

@list_id = "my list id is in here"
gb = Gibbon::API.new

gb.lists.subscribe({
  double_opt_in: false,
  :id => @list_id,
  :email => {:email => params[:email][:address]}
  })
end
```

initializers/gibbon.rb:

```
Gibbon::API.api_key = "my api key is in here"
Gibbon::API.timeout = 15
Gibbon::API.throws_exceptions = false
```

routes.rb:

```
post 'welcome/subscribe' => 'welcome#subscribe'
  root 'welcome#index'
```

controllers/welcome_controller.rb:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def subscribe

    @list_id = "my list id is in here"
    gb = Gibbon::API.new

    gb.lists.subscribe({
      double_opt_in: false,
      :id => @list_id,
      :email => {:email => params[:email][:address]}
      })
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with this code here: [Mailchimp gem double_optin false not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35117053/mailchimp-gem-double-optin-false-not-working)

but having issues with double opt-in => false