# Mailchimp gem double_optin false not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mailchimp

double opt-in confirmation email still goes through, any idea what's wrong? Was having problems with the gibbon gem, so opted for mailchimp gem instead.

Gemfile

```
gem "mailchimp-api", "~> 2.0.4"
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_action :setup_mcapi

  def setup_mcapi
    @mc = Mailchimp::API.new('mailchimp api key goes here')
    @list_id = "list id goes here"
  end

end
```

welcome_controller.rb

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def subscribe
    email = params[:email][:address]

    if !email.blank?

      begin

        @mc.lists.subscribe(@list_id, {'email' => email}, 'double_optin' => false)
      end

      respond_to do |format|
        format.json{render :json => {:message => "Success!"}}
      end

    rescue Mailchimp::ListAlreadySubscribedError

      respond_to do |format|
        format.json{render :json => {:message => "#{email} is already subscribed to the list"}}
      end

    rescue Mailchimp::ListDoesNotExistError

      respond_to do |format|
        format.json{render :json => {:message => "The list could not be found."}}
      end

    rescue Mailchimp::Error => ex

      if ex.message

        respond_to do |format|
          format.json{render :json => {:message => "There is an error. Please enter valid email id."}}
        end

      else

        respond_to do |format|
          format.json{render :json => {:message => "An unknown error occurred."}}
        end
      end

    end

  else

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json{render :json => {:message => "Email Address Cannot be blank. Please enter valid email id."}}
    end

  end
end

end
```

index.html.erb

```
<h3>Add a New Member</h3>
<p>Please enter your email address to subscribe to our newsletter.</p>
<%= form_tag('/welcome/subscribe', method: "post", id: "welcome", remote: "true") do -%>
   <%= email_field(:email, :address, {id: "email", placeholder: "email address"}) %>
   <%= submit_tag("Subscribe") %>
<% end %>
<div id="response">Response Will be displayed here</div>
```

routes.rb

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'welcome#index'
  post 'welcome/subscribe' => 'welcome#subscribe'

end
```

Answer (score 1):

From [mailchimp-api document](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mailchimp-api/2.0.4/Mailchimp/Lists#subscribe-instance_method)

> subscribe(id, email, merge_vars = nil, email_type = 'html', double_optin = true, update_existing = false, replace_interests = true, send_welcome = false) ⇒ Hash

The `double_optin` is the parameter which will be passed directly not like what you did.

So, it will be:

```
@mc.lists.subscribe(@list_id, email, nil, 'html', false)
```

Comment: with that I'm now getting an ex.message error for any email that I try to submit. 
        `rescue Mailchimp::Error => ex

            if ex.message

              respond_to do |format|
                format.json{render :json => {:message => "There is an error. Please enter valid email id."}}
              end `

Answer (score 0):

The answer above kept giving me errors, this worked for me:

```
@mc.lists.subscribe(@list_id, { "email" => email }, merge_vars = nil, email_type = 'html', double_optin = false)
```

Comment: Try explaining how this answer is different from the one above. This might be better as a comment on the other answer instead.